# Unrooting phone

Tags: root-access, factory-reset, uninstallation, hard-reset

I bought a new phone from someone the other day and I would like to use it. The only problem is when I was going through it I noticed that they at some point rooted their phone and put some of there own system files and apps into the system. I can't access the root of this device; I have been trying for days now and I don't want to put my information into this phone till I have been able to wipe it clean of the old user's root system data. How can I force reset this phone to wipe not just the local user data but also the system user data they put into?

Comment: You will have to reflash it with the factory stock image. The system partition in memory cannot be returned to stock in any other way as in almost all devices there is no way to make to changes to the system without root access. What exact phone make and model do you have and we may be able to assist?

Comment: its the lg harmony 2 make is lm-x410cs. i would need someone to tell me how to do this in detail im new to all of this and have been for some time.

Comment: there is no official ROM available, so this is just theory https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJ_8xuuftZw but you can ask previous owner how to get root privileges